# Extracting value of a json in Spark SQl

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am looking to aggregate by extracting the value of a json key here from one of the column here. can someone help me with the right syntax in Spark SQL

select count(distinct(Name)) as users, xHeaderFields['xyz'] as app group by app order by users desc

The table column is something like this. I have removed other columns for simplification.Table has columns like Name etc.

[image]

Comment: Do you want an array of values as a result? or?

Comment: yes .. I need the values of only "xyz" key in xHeaderFields.. as you see there are other keys as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataset is called `ds` and there is only one `key=xyz` object per columns;

First, to JSON conversion (if needed):

```
ds = ds.withColumn("xHeaderFields", expr("from_json(xHeaderFields, 'array<struct<key:string,value:string>>')"))
```

Then filter the `key = xyz` and take the first element (assuming there is only one `xyz` key):

```
.withColumn("xHeaderFields", expr("filter(xHeaderFields, x -> x.key == 'xyz')[0]"))
```

Finally, extract value from your object:

```
.withColumn("xHeaderFields", expr("xHeaderFields.value"))
```

Final result:

```
+-------------+
|xHeaderFields|
+-------------+
|null         |
|null         |
|Settheclass  |
+-------------+
```

Good luck!